# Why converting new.Date() .toISOString() changes the time?

Tags: javascript, date, toisostring

I'm inserting a date in a database in two different format.

**this is inserting as Datetime**

```
    var mydate;
    mydate = new Date();
    document.getElementById('clockinhour').value = mydate.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

**Output A**

```
2017-06-21 20:14:31
```

**this is inserting as varchar :**

```
document.getElementById('clocked_in_time').value = Date();
```

**Output B**

```
Wed Jun 21 2017 16:14:31 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Output B is the correct time but I need to display output A. What causes the time to change when converted toISOString? How can I fix this?

Comment: `Output B is the correct time but I need to display output A`, do you mean display in the format that output A is?

Comment: Does this mean you would like to display the date time in EST format and not ISO format?

Comment: [*RTFM*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring): "*The time zone is always UTC, denoted by the suffix Z*",

Comment: Question is repeat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300956/whats-the-difference-between-datetime-in-iso-8601-and-utc-formats-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between datetime in ISO 8601 and UTC formats in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300956/whats-the-difference-between-datetime-in-iso-8601-and-utc-formats-in-javascript)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: I use datetime output A to make calculations in the database. It is used to calculate timediff between two dates and show user total time they have worked. Output B is proper time that's what I mean, it's 16h00(4pm) not 20h00(8pm).

Comment: @Jaya: Somehow yes. Whatever time they are in.

Answer (score 12):

In your **this is inserting as Datetime** block your `slice` are stripping of the timezone part (the `Z` at the end of `toISOString` output):

```
document.getElementById('clockinhour').value = mydate.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

As pointed out by @RobG in the comments section, `toISOString` should always return the date in UTC (`Z` or `+00:00`).

> [RTFM](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring):
>   "*The time zone [offset] is always UTC, denoted by the suffix Z*",

The time "changes" because it is converted to UTC when you calls `toISOString`.

If you want to get ISO date in your timezone, you should take a look in these two questions: [How to ISO 8601 format a Date with Timezone Offset in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17415579/3136474) and [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3552461/3136474)

Answer (score 5):

ISO time is time zone free. You'll notice with b you have time zone GMT-04:00 if you add those four hours to the 16 hours in the Date, you get 20