# toISOString() return the wrong data at first april

Tags: javascript

I use the method `toISOString()` to convert a date into a ISO String

```
 console.log(date);
 var x = date.toISOString();
 console.log(x);
```

My input date-object contains the following data 
`Wed Apr 01 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)`

The output of `toISOString()` is `2020-03-31T23:00:00.000Z`

I try to find a solution and explaination about this strange result, because it happens only by the 1st of April - and this is not an april joke. Does somebody can explain the behavior? Or can give me a hint, how I can get the correct value?

Comment: How is Date set?

Comment: Different timezones, but the date is the same.

Comment: So what's the problem? The ISO string is in UTC while your input date is in GMT+2. They are the same date.

Comment: There is no problem, both  represent exactly the same instant in time, just with different offsets to UTC

Comment: _“because it happens only by the 1st of April - and this is not an april joke. Does somebody can explain the behavior?”_ - you might want to go check when DST ends in 2020 ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why converting new.Date() .toISOString() changes the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44689770/why-converting-new-date-toisostring-changes-the-time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple.
Your timezone is +0200 `GMT`, and `toISOString()` gives you `Zulu` time. Everything is correct here.

Comment: and this problem occures only at the 1st April?

Comment: @michael-mammut what input did you expect to get? You ask for an iso string, you get the iso string.. no problem.

Comment: if i send `toISOString Wed Apr 01 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)`to the `toISOString()` method, the method returns `2020-03-31T23:00:00.000Z` . So why the date has changed, and how can i prevent it? I expacte an ISO String of the 1.April 2020.

Comment: _“So why the date has changed”_ - **it hasn’t**. When you subtract 2 hours from 1:00 in the morning, then of course you land at 23:00 _the previous day_ ... What _has_ changed, is that your local time zone is now ahead of UTC by _two_ hours, whereas “yesterday” it was only ahead by one hour. Again: **DST** is the issue here.