# Javascript | Get Current UTC DateTime In DateTime Format - Not String

Tags: javascript, datetime

The codes below return current UTC datetime in string format.
But i am looking for a function in javascript that return current utc datetime in datetime format.
It seems there is no such that function in javascript.

```js
var dateTime_now = new Date();
var dateTime_now_utc_str = dateTime_now.toUTCString();
alert(dateTime_now_utc_str);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Javascript dates are already in UTC? The methods you call on the object are what determine if the results are in the local or GMT+0 timezones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### .toISOString() is what you want, not .toUTCString()

You already have the Javascript *internal* DateTime format in the variable `dateTime_now`. So I think you do want a string output, but not the string `Sun, 05 Dec 2021 06:11:15 GMT`, because it contains useless strings like `Sun` and useful, but non-numerical strings like `Dec`. I am guessing you do want a string output, but containing digits and separators and no words.

```js
var dateTime_now = new Date();
var dateTime_now_utc_str = dateTime_now.toISOString();
console.log(dateTime_now_utc_str);

// Result:      2021-12-05T06:10:54.299Z
```

#### Why?

A detailed explanation of why is given here, by me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58347604/7549483

In short, UTC simply means "in the timezone of GMT+0", while ISO is the name of the format *yyyy-mm-dd* etc. The full name of the date format is ISO 8601.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what you mean by DateTime format. Did you mean Javascript's internal DateTime format? In which case you already have that in the variable `dateTime_now`, don't you? If not, can you give an example of what you mean by DateTime format?

Comment: Have you tried using the `new Intl.DateTimeFormat()` object?

Comment: Please don't post images, post text. There really is no reason to post an image of a wikipedia page, it shouldn't be used as a reference anyway. If there is an answer for the question already, then close it as a duplicate.